# How do I glue glass top to a wooden base

Tags: wood, glass

I made a log table and now I'm trying to put a glass top as you can see in the picture.

The issue is that the glass top is not sticking to the log. I tried various things such as clear adhesive bumper pads etc from Lowes but nothing is working. The bond is not strong enough and I have two seven years old who keep bumping into the table.

Does anyone know what I should be using to glue the glass top to the top of the log.

[image: log with glass top]

Comment: I'd be hesitant to permanently attach the glass - I shudder at the thought of moving that as one unit...

Comment: This may be doomed to fail. Wood moves with changes in humidity, glass does not. If you get really great glue, you may break the glass. Otherwise, the glue bond will break as the wood moves.

Comment: Might be worth a trip to a large furniture store to see how commercial manufacturers solve this problem. (The answer may be "they don't try", but...)

Answer (score 5):

Suction cups are used with success in this situation.  Search for "glass table suction cups".  The cups have a small cylindrical nub that sits in a hole you will have to drill for each cup. You should only need about four.  With the suction cups, the table would be secure, would have some (minimal) give when struck, and would be easy to replace.

[image: Suction Cups]

Answer (score 1):

It is inside the house in a controlled environment, the expansion/contraction of the wood should be fairly minimized. Use a flexible adhesive like clear silicone, make sure you get the type that says it cures crystal clear. Put a few nice big dollops and it will hold.

Not sure I like the idea of a large unprotected sheet of glass around a couple of 7 year old kids, it's gonna get broken and when it does I hope nobody gets hurt.

Comment: I grew up in a house with a glass coffee table, and I turned out good!  No glass breaky, but some head smacky.

Comment: I'm sure... I hope....  it is tempered glass. If so, it'd very hard to break, especially with the rug beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

I make a table like this in my shop.  And we actually take it to markets, trade shows etc. Magnets! Embed a rare earth magnet in the top.   We use a forstener bit the size of the magnet  we are going to imbed.  You don't need much one or two 1/2- 3/4 OD magnets.  Rare earth magnets are readily available at Cheapot.   Then just use your magnet on the top.  Works perfect.  You can even plug over your magnet in the stump and still get it to pull with a bigger magnet.

If you're searching for total aesthetics the crystal silicone around the OUTSIDE perimeter of stump works perfect.  Then you can remove with a razor blade.  Helps to level the glass too!

Comment: How does a DIYer attach magnets to glass?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might be able to epoxy a large pin (something like a nail, but bigger) to the center of the glass, and drill a hole in the base for it to slide into. Something vaguely like this clevis pin (image from McMaster-Carr) which can be had in a 1" x 6" size for under $10. You would want to either drill the glass and glue the pin through it, or at minimum roughen the glass where you'd be gluing the head of the pin onto the bottom side. Either of which may not be possible if the glass is tempered.

[image: Clevis pin from McMaster]

Answer (score 0):

Try a toughened smoke glass top pre-drilled to secure to your log base. Clear glass unless totally supported is a bad idea. You put stickers on your French windows so that you don't walk into them and clear glass table tops can also create the same illusion of not being there!

Comment: Toughened glass will shatter if you attempt to drill it.  And surely nobody puts stickers on french windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this, I bought these 4 round metal cylinders, that you buy screws for 8 MM
And screw them to the table, after you use a clear glass top glue.
I bought them
On amazon, but the screws I bought at Home Depot 8 MM plu the glue.   Love my table stump!!!

Link:  [https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Thread-Diameter-Aluminum-Hardware/dp/B01N3QSW4Q/ref=sr_1_34?keywords=glass+attach+screw&qid=1636222114&sr=8-34](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N3QSW4Q)

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. As it stands, your answer is a bit difficult to interpret. Please [edit] it to clarify your thoughts, and maybe even include a picture or two. It's also acceptable to include links to products (or product categories "round cylinders like these" is fine) you'd recommend, just be sure to indicate whether or not you have any affiliation with the vendor or manufacturer you're recommending, otherwise it could be construed as spam.